# Can't download updates on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

A message is coming on screen when I'm trying to download updates. It says:

```
Report this bug against update manager package.
```

and then:

```
E: Malformed line 54 in source list/etc/apt/sources.list(dist parse)
```

Comment: What command exactly are you using? What does your question have to do with Firefox? Did you change anything in the `sources.list` file? Can you post the contents of the file here, please?

Comment: -1, can you please edit this to clearly state your question?

Comment: I would update the source.list file then try again.  There is a command to download the current source.list I just don't have it handy.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in line 54 of your /etc/apt/sources.list I can't really explain that too much more clearly.  It's just saying that that line is not in the correct format, or perhaps that you deleted one of the pounds, so something that should have been a comment is now getting read.